# Perforce (P4) - How can I submit all changes to files and directories?

Tags: linux, perforce

I have a sandbox that I've completely reworked in the past several weeks. This includes modifying, creating, and deleting both files and directories within this sandbox.

How can I add *all* of these changes to a new change-list in Perforce? Can it be done with a single command?

I've tried `find . -type f -print | p4 -x - add`, but this gives me multiple errors for files, saying `can't add existing file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
p4 reconcile
```

This will open all the files.  Follow it up with:

```
p4 submit
```